# Core Data Migration properties offset on iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, ios7

I am doing a migration from a older version of Core Data Model to a newer one. I am just adding some new properties for the already existing entities. I have inspired from this tutorial and made a progressive migration mechanism for the future migration that I will need.

[core-data-migration](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/core-data-migration.html)

I have a problem that happens only on `iOS 7`. I tested on iOS 7.1.2 and iOS 7.0.1.

**The problem** is that after migration all the properties get a offset like this:

**Before Migration:**

```
Entity.prop1 = value1

Entity.prop2 = value2

Entity.prop3 = value3
```

**After Migration:**

```
Entity.prop1 = value2

Entity.prop2 = value3

Entity.prop3 = nil
```

I have tried doing the migration manually with `NSEntityMigrationPolicy` and without it and it's still the same thing. On `iOS 8` devices works good.

I checked the SQLITE

Do you have any ideea why is this happening?

Comment: Could be that the migration is correct but you are reading the variables wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The journal_mode of the Database was WAL.

The problem was that the sql database had a .sql-wal file that was lost during migration and left me with a corrupted database.

I solved this problem by changing the journal mode from WAL to DELETE before the migration:

```
NSError *WALToDELETEMigrationError = nil;
NSDictionary *options = @{NSSQLitePragmasOption: @{@"journal_mode": @"DELETE"}};

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *tempPersistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:oldModel];

NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[LVCoreDataController FilesStoreDirectory] error:nil];

if (![tempPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:type configuration:nil URL:sourceStoreURL options:options error:&WALToDELETEMigrationError]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", WALToDELETEMigrationError);
}
```